# Web scraping in Python using Beautiful Soup to find a specific table

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am a using Beautiful Soup to scrap a webpage from wikipedia. Webpage has several tables and I am trying to access one specific table. Class name of table is 'wikitable' but there are few other tables with the same class name. When I use code below I get the first table on the webpage. But I need the second table.

```
my_table = str(soup.find("table","wikitable"))
```

I also tried to use the caption but it did not work.

```
soup.find("caption", text="Demographics of student body").find_parent("table")
```

I got an error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_parent'"

Here is what HTML code looks like for the table I am trying to access.

```
<table style="text-align:center; float:left; font-size:85%; margin-right:2em;" class="wikitable">
<caption><i>Demographics of student body</i><sup id="cite_ref-Head_count_124-0" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-Head_count-124">[124]</a></sup><sup id="cite_ref-125" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-125">[125]</a></sup><sup id="cite_ref-126" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-126">[126]</a></sup></caption>
```

I will appreciate any guidance. I am using Python 3.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `find` method returns only the 1st match, you should use `find_all` and select the 2nd item.

```
my_table = soup.find_all("table", class_="wikitable")[1]
```

If you prefer css selectors:

```
my_table = soup.select('table.wikitable')[1]
```

The `AttributeError` exception is raised because the string you're looking for belongs to the 'i' tag inside 'caption', so `find` returns `None`. You can make it work if you select 'i'.

```
my_table = soup.find("i", string="Demographics of student body").find_parent("table")
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I did not realize that you can use [n] to access any table.